# Django, using the same view depending on if its a GET or an AJAX POST method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

So I am using the same view in Django to do two things, depending on if the request is a GET or a POST method.

The GET method is simply to render the page when the user requests it, and the POST is when I use ajax to send information from the frontend, to the view so that i can process it and save it in the database.

Here is the Javascript/Ajax:

```
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
        'vals': vals
        },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //On sunccess
    }
    });
```

The window.location.pathname contains the review_id in it and looks like:

```
/reviews/*ID*/add_questions/
```

This is my Django View:

```
def add_questions(request, review_id = None):
#print('yes')
if request.method == 'GET':
    try:
        review = ReviewBlock.objects.get(pk = review_id)
        args = {'review': review}
        return render(request, 'add_questions.html', args)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Page not found</h1>')
elif request.method == 'POST':
    print(review_id)
```

As you can see, I have a print statement to see if the ajax call is working, however, it never prints it in the console.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think you should check your urls.py file. Check whether you have properly configured your view or not for request. One more thing you will get review_id only when it is GET request. From your JS code it looks like you are making post request. Add few more things like your urls.py to make it more clear.

Comment: is the "yes" print statment printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) defaults to GET requests. To do a POST request, you either need to add `type: "POST",`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  ...
```

or use the [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) shortcut

```
$.post({
  url: url,
  ...
```

If you use the same request method for ajax and non-ajax requests, you may find the [`request.is_ajax()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) method useful